# Good regex for various decimal numbers

Tags: regex

I have the following five numbers, some of them decimals some of them integers:

```
18384
-1029374
0.29292
.039384
-.0334
4.
```

What would be a good regex to match these? So far I have the following:

```
^[-+]?((\d+)|(\.\d+))$
```

But this fails on `0.29292`. What would be a better one?

Comment: `^[-+]?\d*\.?\d+$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's much better than mine, but wouldn't match something like `4.` . (added that example into my question).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Which one of those answers here `Match regex with numeric value and decimal `  is the correct answer to this question ? The accepted answer was lifted off of a different post. It seems there is a few hundred answers that use the core `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)` which was originally posted by quite a few years ago.  Yeah, so which one answers this OP's question. Mine answers it specifically, or is it up to you to decide ?

Comment: @x15 the accepted answer doesn't actually work for the above inputs / address the question (nor does Wiktor's answer, for that matter). Thank you for your answer, that is what i was looking for.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 -The question of duplicates seems to already have the answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390629/should-stack-overflow-remove-the-regex-tag). Marking as duplicate is a good way to hide both the question and answers from public view. Not deleted but hard to find and upvote / downvote as necessary. If this question were a duplicate, it's not, then that one referenced from 2018 is a little too recent, as this `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)` technique has been around since regex was invented, and certainly used thousands of times on SO before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covering all the bases for a numeric parse could be this:

`^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?$`

https://regex101.com/r/VGb2s1/1

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 [+-]? 
 (?:
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )
 (?: [eE] [+-]? \d+ )?
 $
```

Removing all whitespace before using regex would be better.