# regexp to validate a non-zero number

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

My requirement is to validate a NON-ZERO number. The regular expression that I used is the following.

```
^[1-9]?\d+(\.\d)?\d*$
```

VALID VALUES should be

- 2
- 22
- 2222 (up to any number of digits)
- 2.2222 (up to any number of decimal points)

INVALID VALUES

- 0
- 1. (. without decimal values)
- 0.1 (any number of decimals, but start digit is 0)
- 2.4.5 (more than one .)

basically any values starting with 0 or has more than one . or no decimal points provided when . is added, are INCORRECT.

Comment: would 0938435 be valid?

Comment: no 938435 should be valid. if start with 0, then it should be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?$`

https://regex101.com/r/wHZUoW/1

-Since you don't want the number to start with `0`, you shouldn't make the `[1-9]` at the beginning optional with `?`.

-As general good practice, a non-capturing group `(?: ... )` is used instead of a capturing group, because the contents do not need to be referenced later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to validate your numbers:

```
^(?=[1-9])\d*\.?\d+$
```

It uses a regex proposed by @WiktorStribiżew as a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58719826/good-regex-for-various-decimal-numbers) to match decimal numbers (`^\d*\.?\d+$`), and adds a positive lookahead to ensure that the first character of the number is not 0. Note that if you want to allow numbers such as `.3`, you should add `.` to the lookahead character class i.e. `^(?=[1-9.])\d*\.?\d+$`

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BrPEpi/1)

Answer (score 1):

`[1-9]+[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?` should work for your case.

`[1-9]+` will make sure that the expression starts with a number different than 0.

`[0-9]*` will make sure to allow the expression to have zeros after the first digit.

`(\.[0-9]+)?` will allow an extension to the expression, which has to have a `.` and at least 1 number after it. The `?` in the end makes it optional.

By the way, I really like this website to test my regular expressions: https://regexr.com/, you should try it.

Comment: How will this match `10`?

Comment: 3.05 shouldn't match?

Comment: What about `1x0`?

Comment: yeah, had to wrap `.` with a `[]` to make sure it considers only `.` character, thanks @Nick :)

Comment: A backslash is preferred (see the other answers).